# Trying to change character variable across multiple columns

Tags: r, character

(I'm like super new to R) Trying to  change "si" to "yes" .

I want to get from here:

```
survey_done

column_a column_b
Si         Yes
Si         Si
Yes        No
No         No
No         Si
```

to here:

```
column_a column_b
Yes        Yes
Yes        Yes
Yes        No
No         No
No         Yes
```

I've tried this formula

```
survey_done <-survey_done %%
  recode(across(c(column_a,
                  column_b), "Sí" = "Yes"))
```

but I get an error:

```
Error in `across()`:
! Must be used inside dplyr verbs.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

How can i correct this error. Also is there another formula that allows me to specify the columns?

Answer (score 4):

The `recode` should be within `across` as the input `.x` should be a `vector` (from `?recode`).  We loop `across` the columns of inerest in `mutate` and then apply the `recode` to modify the values in the column

```
library(dplyr)
survey_done <- survey_done %>% 
   mutate(across(c(column_a, column_b), 
       ~ recode(.x,  "Si" = "Yes")))
```

-output

```
survey_done
 column_a column_b
1      Yes      Yes
2      Yes      Yes
3      Yes       No
4       No       No
5       No      Yes
```

---

In `base R`, we could do

```
survey_done[survey_done == "Si"] <- "Yes"
```

#### data

```
survey_done <- structure(list(column_a = c("Si", "Si", "Yes", "No",
 "No"), column_b = c("Yes", 
"Si", "No", "No", "Si")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Thank you sooooo much!!!! the first answer did the trick!!

Answer (score 2):

Another approach using `replace`

```
replace(survey_done, survey_done == "Si", "Yes")
  column_a column_b
1      Yes      Yes
2      Yes      Yes
3      Yes       No
4       No       No
5       No      Yes
```

The `tidy` way

```
library(dplyr)

survey_done %>% 
  mutate(replace(across(1:2), across(1:2) == "Si", "Yes"))
  column_a column_b
1      Yes      Yes
2      Yes      Yes
3      Yes       No
4       No       No
5       No      Yes
```